# Include client SDK usage sample in SwaggerUI

Tags: api, swagger, swagger-ui, documentation-generation, swagger-codegen

I've been searching for a tool which could help me parse my JSON swagger file (or even YAML file) and generate code sample resources in my UI based on [this example](http://api.rakam.io/?php#get-events-of-the-user25) of API doc.

I've already tried :

- codegen (So I do have the code samples in a github repo, but I don't know how to get it on my UI dynamically)
- [slate](https://github.com/buremba/swagger-slate), but i'm trying to go on with swagger
- [Widdershins](https://github.com/Mermade/widdershins)

Does someone knows about a third-party-tool able to produce such a feature or did I miss something from codegen or swagger-UI ? 
Or should I just write all my code samples roughly in my page ?

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it. We can't strickly speaking "include" dynamically SDK usage samples into SwaggerUI.
Nevertheless, you can generate the ui with multiple languages SDK ! It won't look the same but I'll override css anyway.

Wasn't clear for me until I found this [Github issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7037) ! All you have to do is generate html2 client with the editor or codegen...

Everything is implemented in the index.html (which is kinda dirty but still, it works fine !).