# Request Body Template in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is It possible to get swagger request body in php, javascript, ruby, etc in response of swagger instead of only getting curl response template.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you mean "Is there an option or plugin for Swagger UI that would generate code examples in PHP/JavaScript/etc. like, for example, in https://slatedocs.github.io/slate/?"

Comment: yes, exactly what I want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include client SDK usage sample in SwaggerUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604777/include-client-sdk-usage-sample-in-swaggerui)

Comment: See the ^^ linked Q&A - Swagger UI does not support code examples out of the box, but Swagger Codegen's `html2` generator produces docs with embedded code examples.

Comment: Is it possible to change names such as 'API MEHTODS - apiName' to just apiName in sidebar of html2 documentation